# append to a list in jinja2 without "printing" it to the html

Tags: python, html, jinja2

A similar question was asked 7 month ago but got no reply.

I got the following problem:
I want to append to a list in jinj2 within a for loop.

What works is:

```
{% set test = [] %}
{% for i in range(5) %}
    {{ test.append(i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

but it "prints" the return-value of {{test.append(i)}} (which is None) to my html-document. So I have to comment it out

```
<! -- {{ test.append(i) }} -->
```

which executes the jinja-code but "disables" the return-value for html.

however I asked myself, if there is a better solution.

```
{% set test.append(i) %}
```

for example does not work (expected token 'end of statement block', got '(')

Comment: as for me you should create list in code, not in Jinja. All "calculations" should be done before sending to template.

Comment: with this simple example may work `test = list(range(5))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jinja2 prints none when appending to a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850614/jinja2-prints-none-when-appending-to-a-loop)