# Jinja2 prints none when appending to a loop

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

In my flask application I am creating a list and appending.  When I append to the list `None` prints.

```
{% set keyword_list = [] %}
{% for keyword in keywords_data %}
    {{ keyword_list.append(keyword['keywords_id']) }} //None prints for each iteration
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ keyword_list | join(',') }}` prints `1,2,3`
`{{ keyword_list }}` prints `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change it to `{{ keyword_list.append(keyword['keywords_id']) or "" }}`, which uses the feature of `or`s that returns the first truthy answer. Since strings are always truthy in Jinja, and `None` is falsy, it returns the empty string, outputting nothing to the end-user.

Edit: @New Coder asked if there was a less hacky way to do it, and there is! Use `_` as a throwaway variable to store the `None` output, like so: `{% set _ = keyword_list.append(keyword['keywords_id']) %}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. But is there a better way that looks less hacky?

Comment: @NewCoder check my edited answer! Sorry haven't been on SO for a while or I would've answered sooner 

Answer (score 2):

To suppress the output of the append operation, define a new empty variable at the step

```
{%- set keyword_list = [] -%}
{%- for keyword in keywords_data -%}
    {%- _ = keyword_list.append(keyword['keywords_id']) -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

I also suggest you to use the `%- -%` construction to avoid unnecessary whitespaces.

More about the whitespace control in the doc
https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-3-whitespace-control/

Comment: thanks for sharing. I wanted to add a small fix. I think we should use the `set`keyword as below:

`{%- set _ = keyword_list.append(keyword['keywords_id']) -%}`